# How to conditionally select column based on other columns under pandas DataFrame without using where function?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.5

I'm working under `python 2.5` (I'm restricted to that version due to external api) and would like to get same results as below code I wrote under `python 2.7`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"lineId":[1,2,3,4], "idCaseMin": [10, 23, 40, 8], "min": [-110, -205, -80, -150], "idCaseMax": [5, 27, 15, 11], "max": [120, 150, 110, 90]})
df = df.set_index("lineId")

df["idMax"] = df["idCaseMax"].where(df["max"]>abs(df["min"]),df["idCaseMin"])
```

The DataFrame results in:

```
>>> df
        idCaseMax  max  idCaseMin  min  idMax
lineId                                       
1               5   10        120 -110      5
2              27   23        150 -205     23
3              15   40        110  -80     15
4              11    8         90 -150      8
```

The `idMax` column is defined based on the id which gets the greatest value, in absolute module, within `max` and `min` columns.

I can't use `where` function as it's not available under `pandas 0.9.0` (latest version available for `python 2.5`) and `numpy 1.7.1`.

So, which options do I have to get same results for `idMax` column without using `pandas` `where` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [120]: df['idMax'] =  \
              np.where(df["max"]<=abs(df["min"]),
                       df["idCaseMin"],
                       df["idCaseMax"])

In [121]: df
Out[121]:
        idCaseMax  idCaseMin  max  min  idMax
lineId
1               5         10  120 -110      5
2              27         23  150 -205     23
3              15         40  110  -80     15
4              11          8   90 -150      8
```

Comment: OP's pandas v is 0.9, so where doesn't exist... apparently!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i think Numpy where should be there - or am i wrong?

Comment: Actually, I was operating under the assumption that none of the `where` functions existed for 0.9, so I guess my answer is no longer valid. :-(

Comment: Yes, Numpy where clause is there under `numpy 1.7.1` version I have ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, why? It's a working solution and it's faster compared to `.apply(..., axis=1)`

Comment: Based on readability I will select this answer. I find it's clear what the code is doing here. Related to timings I found this way is also the fastest. It took 0.0 seconds to execute (compared to all the rest of the solutions stated till now. e.g. My solution took 0.001 seconds)

Comment: @CedricZoppolo Test it on bigger data. :p

Comment: @COLDSPEED, I tested with 1 million values and still this answer is the fastest. It took 0.024 secs to resolve. My answer took 34 secs, Your answer took 0.27 secs and rest of answers took about 0.05 secs.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try and provide an optimised solution for `0.9.` IIUC `ix` should work here.

```
m = df["max"] > df["min"].abs()

i = df.ix[m, 'idCaseMax']
j = df.ix[~m, 'idCaseMin']

df['idMax'] = i.append(j)
df

        idCaseMax  idCaseMin  max  min  idMax
lineId
1               5         10  120 -110      5
2              27         23  150 -205     23
3              15         40  110  -80     15
4              11          8   90 -150      8
```

Comment: Huh, you don't even need the `sort_index` call, pandas will autoalign the series.

Answer (score 2):

Your pandas should have this...

```
df['idMax']=(df["max"]>abs(df["min"]))* df["idCaseMax"]+(df["max"]<=abs(df["min"]))* df["idCaseMin"]
df
Out[1388]: 
        idCaseMax  idCaseMin  max  min  idMax
lineId                                       
1               5         10  120 -110      5
2              27         23  150 -205     23
3              15         40  110  -80     15
4              11          8   90 -150      8
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `apply` function as below code to attempt same results:

```
df["idMax"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["idCaseMax"] if row["max"]>abs(row["min"]) else row["idCaseMin"], axis = 1)
```